# Select agrupando por media por hora e soma por dia

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-select

Como posso retornar num select a soma diária da coluna valor, Sendo que antes de somar tenho que fazer uma media por hora? Minha tabela recebe o "valor" uma vez por segundo, preciso fazer a média por hora desse valor e retornar a soma dessas medias por dia...

Utilizo o MySQL.

```
valor         time
15      2017-10-13 14:02:06
99      2017-10-13 12:26:57
75      2017-09-25 21:20:08
40      2017-09-25 21:19:32
8       2017-09-16 19:23:16
5       2017-09-16 19:20:48
2.5     2017-09-16 19:20:35
2       2017-08-26 13:46:13
1.41    2017-08-26 13:45:13
1.41    2017-08-26 13:45:12
1.41    2017-08-26 13:45:11
1.41    2017-08-26 13:45:09
1.41    2017-08-26 13:45:08
1.41    2017-08-26 13:45:07
1.41    2017-08-26 13:45:06
1.41    2017-08-26 13:45:05
1.41    2017-08-26 13:45:04
1.41    2017-08-26 13:45:03
1.41    2017-08-26 13:45:02
1.41    2017-08-26 13:45:01
1.41    2017-08-26 13:45:00
1.41    2017-08-26 13:44:59
1.41    2017-08-26 13:44:58
1.41    2017-08-26 13:44:57
1.41    2017-08-26 13:44:55
1.41    2017-08-26 13:44:54
1.41    2017-08-26 13:44:53
1.41    2017-08-26 13:44:52
1.41    2017-08-26 13:44:51
1.41    2017-08-26 13:44:50
1.41    2017-08-26 13:44:49
1.41    2017-08-26 13:44:48
1.41    2017-08-26 13:44:47
1.41    2017-08-26 13:44:46
1.41    2017-08-26 13:44:45
1.41    2017-08-26 13:44:44
1.41    2017-08-26 13:44:42
1.41    2017-08-26 13:44:41
1.41    2017-08-26 13:44:40
1.41    2017-08-26 13:44:39
1.41    2017-08-26 13:44:38
1.41    2017-08-27 13:44:37
1.41    2017-08-27 13:44:36
1.41    2017-08-27 13:44:35
1.41    2017-08-27 13:44:34
1.41    2017-08-27 13:44:33
1.41    2017-08-27 13:44:32
1.41    2017-08-27 13:44:31
1.41    2017-08-27 13:44:30
1.41    2017-08-27 13:44:29
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Select da média por dia:

```
select
    avg(valor) as media,
    cast(data_hora as date) as dia
from valores
group by cast(data_hora as date);
```

> Select da média por dia e hora:

```
select
    avg(valor) as media,
    cast(data_hora as date) as dia,
    hour(data_hora) as hora
from valores
group by cast(data_hora as date),hour(data_hora);
```

> Select da soma das médias por dia e hora, agrupadas pelo dia:

```
select 
    sum(x.media),
    x.dia
from 
    (select
        avg(valor) as media,
        cast(data_hora as date) as dia,
        hour(data_hora) as hora
     from valores
     group by cast(data_hora as date),hour(data_hora)) x
group by x.dia
```

*Particularmente, não vejo aplicação na soma das médias... mas está como pediu.*

Coloquei no SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/25fa97/4

**Referência:**

Função `Hour()`: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_hour

Função `Cast()`: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast

Função `AVG()`: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_avg

Função `SUM()`: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda! Ė que preciso calcular o consumo de energia elétrica diário, mas como a medição é em KW/hora, eu preciso contabilizar a media horaria do registro de corrente, para chegar ao KW/hora, e depois somar por dia. Valeu!!